# How to download other different deb files with apt-get in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ubuntu-12.04, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Is there any way how to download another version of deb files with apt-get in `Ubuntu 12.04`?
In `Ubuntu 12.04`, the default version is `precise`, and when we use the `sudo apt-get install **` command to install packages, the `apt-get` can find the suitable packages automatically. But is there any way to download the deb packages with specific version, such as `Ubuntu 10.04(Lucid)`? 
In my circumstance, I have an `Raspberry Pi`, its main version is `Debian` and its symbol version is `wheezy`. When I use the `sudo apt-get install **`, the network speed is very slow. 
So I want to add the apt source address of `wheezy` into my `Ubuntu 12.04`'s apt source addresses. And use the `Ubuntu 12.04` to download the `wheezy`'s packages, then copy them into the `Raspberry Pi` and install.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A better place for this question http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix Ubuntu and Debian, a number of things are in different locations and will break your system. Use precise with precise, Ubuntu doesn't mix well.

Comment: Hi, thanks, sir.  I have tested some methods. First, I add the wheezy apt source addresses into the /etc/apt/sources.list in Ubuntu 12.04, and in Ubuntu 12.04, do sudo apt-get update, then some apt cache has been created, and I can search some packages of version wheezy. But when I use sudo apt-get download cmake, it says there is no amd64 version. This is because the Raspberry Pi is arm-architecture. So I think if I can give a specific architecture version of the apt, it may work. But I haven't done this successfully.

Comment: The main error is W: Failed to fetch http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/wheezy/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file). So I think if I can replace the amd64 with armhf, it maybe could work.

Comment: The system will break, there is no way to mix packages from both Distros safely.

Comment: OK, thanks. In fact, I just use the `Ubuntu 12.04` to download the deb packages for `wheezy`. In the `Ubuntu 12.04`, I just use `sudo apt-get download **` to download the packages, but not install them. And in some circumstances, this would be work. Today, I have download the `debian-keyring` source package with the `Ubuntu 12.04`, but can't download its binary version for `armhf(arm hard float)`.

Answer (score 1):

I would not recommend installing packages that does not match your OS - you will quickly find yourself in a mess of dependency hell. I would rather recommend that you download the software from the developers webpage, and install it somewhere separate on your system, so its dependencies does not conflict with your entire system.

If you insist, you could go to [launchpad](https://launchpad.net/) and find the package you need, download it and istall it through:

```
sudo dpkg -i the-package-you-downloaded.deb
```

Comment: Hi, thank you, sir. In fact, I have just fell into the trap. Please visit `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893597/illegal-instruction-in-raspberry-pi`, some packages are invalid in the `Raspberry Pi`, so everything start all over again. Very time consuming.