# Illegal instruction in Raspberry Pi

Tags: arm, raspberry-pi, raspbian

Today, I compiled the `opencv-master` downloaded from `github`. With these instructions in the webpage `http://ariandy1.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/raspberry-pi-rasbian-opencv/`, and finally the `OpenCV` compiled successfully. But when I wrote a simple `C++` program, link it with the `-lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_video`, run it in terminal. An error occured, says `Illegal instruction`. But when I remove the `OpenCV`-dependent code, and recompile, it can run successfully. 
I doubt that the packages installed by `apt-get` have some bugs. But I can't find them.
Does anyone face this problem?

The `/etc/apt/sources.list` is:

```
    deb http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ wheezy main contrib non-free rpi
    deb http://www.deb-multimedia.org/ wheezy main non-free
    deb http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
    deb-src http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian wheezy main contrib non-free
```

**UPDATE**

The output of `dmesg` is: http://pastebin.com/dsr8mgVY

**UPDATE 2**

The output of `ldd` command is : http://pastebin.com/s7sUQAbk

**UPDATE 3**

The output of 'file' command is: http://pastebin.com/Q1eaYtjk

Comment: Wait, which opencv, where? I guess you should have a library compiled for raspberry, and maybe one compiled for your development computer. Diw you link the C++ program with the raspberry you just downloaded, and built, or maybe compiled it with another one?

Comment: Anyways, you are doing all this on a PI, without a separate machine? Then yes, there could be something wrong with those packages,

Comment: Hi, thank you. First, I install some packages by `apt-get`, such as `libgtk2.0-dev,libpng++-dev, and so on`. Then I download the latest `OpenCV` from `github`. Then, in the `Raspberry Pi`, the `OpenCV` has been successfully. But when I link the program with some basic `OpenCV` libraries, the program can't run in `Raspberry Pi`. The error is `Illegal instruction`. And I can't find which package is invalid in `ARM`-architecture.

Comment: Yes, all are done in the `PI`. No cross compile.

Comment: @Nicolas Why not uninstall or purge all of those packages and install the ones you just compiled instead? Sounds like you installed some packages with wrong architecture (like you talked about in your other question here on SO. Try apt-get purge all the packages and start all over. After you compiled the software you can do a sudo make install and the packages should be get installed on the system.

Comment: @Bolli, no, the packages installed on `PI` are not downloaded in the `Ubuntu 12.04`, they are all installed by `apt-get` in `Raspberry Pi` with the `/etc/apt/sources.list` above. Three packages are compiled successfully in `Raspberry Pi`, they are `x264, ffmpeg and v4l-utils`.

Comment: @Nicolas okay..  You say you get this error from using these libs (lopencv_core -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_video) in a simple C++ program. Could you try use one lib at a time in your C++ program, to find which one is making the error? Then when you found the one, purge/uinstall it and try apt-get it again. If it still does not work, you could try building it from source - you can even do that with apt-get (http://lumiera.org/documentation/user/tutorials/DebianBuilding.html)

Comment: @Bolli, really a simple solution! I'll try it. By the way, the opencv is compiled from source code, not by `apt-get`.

Comment: Check & paste dmesg for some crash trace

Comment: @auselen, Hi, sir, I have updated the post, please check it.

Comment: @auselen, I also paste it in the http://pastebin.com/dsr8mgVY.

Comment: @Nicolas try to ldd the binary to get all the shared libraries required to run it, then to a "file libname.so" for each library shown. If it's a bad library you should find it now. Or you can do an ltrace or strace of the binary (assuming you have those tools installed).

Comment: @sessyargc.jp, Hi, sir, I have updated the post. Please check the `UPDATE 2` and `UPDATE 3`. It seems all the shared libraries are compatible.

Comment: dmesg doesn't contain any information related to crash. I would expect some backtrace, etc.

Comment: Keep in mind that some library functions might do illegal instructions as a result of panic/fail/error kind of calls.

Comment: @auselen, sorry, I have deleted the binary files. I recompile the `OpenCV` without `ffmpeg`, and the error has gone. I think the error was mainly from the `ffmpeg`. I did all the things under the webpage `http://ariandy1.wordpress.com/2013/02/13/raspberry-pi-rasbian-opencv/`, but with the latest packages `ffmpeg-2.2.tar.gz, v4l-utils-1.0.1.tar.bz2 and x264-snapshot-20140406-2245.tar.bz2`, and the error occurred.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact reasons of the `Illegal instruction in Raspberry Pi`, but I find a solution. Just recompile `OpenCV` with `-DWITH_FFMPEG:BOOL='0'`. Without the `ffmpeg`, the video camera still works.

Comment: @sessyargc.jp, thanks, sir. But the `OpenCV` compiled without `ffmpeg` can't support writing videos. And I also tried to install `ffmpeg` by `sudo apt-get install ffmpeg`, then compiled `OpenCV` with `ffmpeg`, but the error still exists. And I also tried to add `backtrace` function into the program, but when linked with the `OpenCV` shared libraries, the error still exists with no backtrace information shown. I'm not familiar with the backtrace and should learn more about it.

Comment: Compile with debug info and use gdb could be an option.